# CSS меню с поиском и картинками!

Tags: html, css

Помогите подправить CSS что бы поиск был с права меню, а перед поиском выбор языка, выбор языка надо сделать одной кнопкой с выпадающим меню где выбирать язык с картинкой флага.
Сильно не пинайте CSS почти не знаю)

```css
/* Reset */
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* Menu */
.menu { 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
/* Links */
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }
.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }
/* Sub Menu */
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #1f2024;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }
.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
/* Icons */
.menu a.documents { background: url(../img/docs.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.messages { background: url(../img/bubble.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.signout { background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Шаблоны</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="documents">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="messages">Flash</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Контакты</a></li>
  <li><a href="/register">Регистрация</a></li>
  <div class="lang">
    <li><a href="/ru">RU</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en">EN</a></li>
  </div>
  <input type="text"/>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надеюсь, что javascript вы знаете, потому что в меню все таки надо будет внедрять некоторые JS вставки (например, при выборе языка)

```css
/* Reset */
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* Menu */
.menu { 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
/* Links */
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }
.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }
/* Sub Menu */
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #1f2024;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }
.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
/* Icons */
.menu a.documents { background: url(../img/docs.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.messages { background: url(../img/bubble.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.signout { background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 6px center; }

.text {
    margin: 6px;
    height: 20px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Шаблоны</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="documents">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="messages">Flash</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Контакты</a></li>
  <li><a href="/register">Регистрация</a></li>
  <div class = 'right'>
    <li><a href="#">RU</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/ru">RU</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en">EN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <input class = 'text' type="text"/>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: можете поправить выбор языка, тоже с правой стороны, большее спасибо. JS знаю. спасибо!

Comment: держите, но посмотрев как был реализован пример несложно было бы понять как его применить и к нескольким объектам, а не только к одному